# Sencha touch 2.4 - Unable to use AppName.app.function()

Tags: android, ios, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch

I have an app made from sencha touch 2.2.1 and command 3.6 and packaged using cordova 2.9. Was been having deprecation problems and now trying to move it to 2.4 and command 5.0 packaged with cordova 3.5.

But i am unable to use `AppName.app.getController('controller name').controllerFunctioname();` function to call a specific function from a controller. It as been working fine when i was using 2.2.1. It is working fine without building, but after building using sencha app build, it is not working.

I aso tried to use `Ext.app.Application.instance`, `Ext.app.Application.appInstance`, they are also not working after build.

Comment: it must be a configuration issue because the `getController` method works fine, just as you've described. But it's hard to tell the issue from the details you provided.

Comment: Can you provide sample configuration? And where should i configure?